# How to join across tables?

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010

So I have a somewhat complex database which I'm sure could have been implemented better, but I'm stuck trying to create a table using SQL which would JOIN some field and use aggregate functions on others to return specific values that I would then place into a report form.

There are five main tables at play here

ALL_DATES: Contains 2 fields, first being unique ID, and next being every month in "MM/1/YYYY" format from a designated point in time until the current month. The purpose of this table is for a left outer join to query the data/calculations from the PT_LEVEL table for all months since July 2010.

PT_LEVEL: Contains many fields on patient specific metrics. For our purposes we will use the [UNIT],[INF_SITE_MAJ], [SPECIF_SITE], [INF_MONTH], and [INF_YEAR]

V_GROUP_UNIT: This table has several fields and was created to allow a one to many relationship for GROUP(many) can be paired to a PT_LEVEL.UNIT

UNIT_DATA: This table has numbers for days spent on certain devices or in a room. We need these number for the coming calculations.

NHSN_BM:This table contains benchmarking data from a specific government entity for us to compare against, based on the PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR] and again will be aggregated later.

This is my SQL Code which tells me I have a syntax error (operator missing) in MS Access.

```
SELECT * FROM(

SELECT 
ALL_DATES.[ALL_DATES],
V_GROUP_UNIT.[GROUP], 
PT_LEVEL.[UNIT], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF SITE MAJ], 
PT_LEVEL.[SPECIF SITE], 
Count(PT_LEVEL.[INF SITE MAJ]) AS [TOT/INF], 
Sum(UNIT_DATA.[PT_DAYS]) AS SumOfPT_DAYS, 
Sum(UNIT_DATA.[CVC_DAYS]) AS SumOfCVC_DAYS, 
Avg(NHSN_BM.[CLABSI_BM]) AS AvgOfCLABSI_BM, 
Avg(NHSN_BM.[CLABSI_UR_M]) AS AvgOfCLABSI_UR_M, 
Sum(UNIT_DATA.[IUC_DAYS]) AS SumOfIUC_DAYS, 
Avg(NHSN_BM.[CAUTI_BM]) AS AvgOfCAUTI_BM, 
Avg(NHSN_BM.[CAUTI_UR_M]) AS AvgOfCAUTI_UR_M, 
Sum(UNIT_DATA.[VENT_DAYS]) AS SumOfVENT_DAYS, 
Avg(NHSN_BM.[VAP_BM]) AS AvgOfVAP_BM, 
Avg(NHSN_BM.[VAP_UR_M]) AS AvgOfVAP_UR_M

FROM ALL_DATES 

    LEFT JOIN PT_LEVEL ON
    ALL_DATES.[ALL_MONTH] = PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH] AND
    ALL_DATES.[ALL_YEAR] = PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR],

PT_LEVEL    
    INNER JOIN UNIT_DATA ON 
    (PT_LEVEL.[UNIT] = UNIT_DATA.[UNIT]) AND
    (PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH] = UNIT_DATA.[MONTH]) AND 
    (PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR] = UNIT_DATA.[YEAR])

    INNER JOIN V_GROUP_UNIT ON 
    (PT_LEVEL.[UNIT] = V_GROUP_UNIT.[UNIT]) 

    INNER JOIN NHSN_BM ON 
    (PT_LEVEL.[UNIT] = NHSN_BM.[UNIT_LIST]) AND 
    (PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR] = NHSN_BM.[NHSN_BM_YEAR])

GROUP BY 
V_GROUP_UNIT.[GROUP], 
PT_LEVEL.[UNIT], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF SITE MAJ], 
PT_LEVEL.[SPECIF SITE]

HAVING 
(((PT_LEVEL.[INF SITE MAJ]) In ("VAE","BSI","UTI")) AND 
((PT_LEVEL.[SPECIF SITE]) In ("CLABSI","CAUTI","VAC","IVAC","POSSIBLE VAP","PROBABLE VAP")))

ORDER BY 
V_GROUP_UNIT.[GROUP], 
PT_LEVEL.[UNIT], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH], 
PT_LEVEL.[INF SITE MAJ]

) AS QUERY1;
```

I think where I'm messing up is trying to use two parent tables essentially but any insight would be helpful.

Comment: HAVING 
(((PT_LEVEL.[INF SITE MAJ]) In ("VAE","BSI","UTI")) AND 
((PT_LEVEL.[SPECIF SITE]) In ("CLABSI","CAUTI","VAC","IVAC","POSSIBLE VAP","PROBABLE VAP"))) Instead of these in having, use them in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The comma and extra "PT_LEVEL" looks wrong to me:

```
    LEFT JOIN PT_LEVEL ON
    ALL_DATES.[ALL_MONTH] = PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH] AND
    ALL_DATES.[ALL_YEAR] = PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR],

PT_LEVEL    
    INNER JOIN UNIT_DATA ON 
    (PT_LEVEL.[UNIT] = UNIT_DATA.[UNIT]) AND
    (PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH] = UNIT_DATA.[MONTH]) AND 
    (PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR] = UNIT_DATA.[YEAR])
```

What if you replaced it with this:

```
LEFT JOIN PT_LEVEL ON
ALL_DATES.[ALL_MONTH] = PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH] AND
ALL_DATES.[ALL_YEAR] = PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR]

INNER JOIN UNIT_DATA ON 
(PT_LEVEL.[UNIT] = UNIT_DATA.[UNIT]) AND
(PT_LEVEL.[INF_MONTH] = UNIT_DATA.[MONTH]) AND 
(PT_LEVEL.[INF_YEAR] = UNIT_DATA.[YEAR])
```